# RectangularAnnotation in WinForms Chart control not tracking properly with changing axis limits

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, charts

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 doing a WinForms project using charting tools and finding I'm having an issue with the rendering of a RectangularAnnotation that I'm using to highlight a small region of noteworthy data in a specific band of X values.

The problem is, though I set the annotation to remain in a fixed position covering the entire Y-axis range, I'm finding that the rendering of the annotation rectangle changes unexpectedly when my series values and axis limits change. I prepared a number of images that illustrate the problem but since I'm new here I've been restricted from inserting them in this post. I'll try to describe my methods as briefly as possible.

I created a Winforms project with a Chart from System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting namespace, then added a line series with about a dozen Points. My XValues (wavelength) range from about 350 to 1000 at regular intervals and my YValues are random percentages.

Then I added a RectangularAnnotation that appears as a colored vertical strip covering from, say, 600 to 800 along the X-axis (eventually the user will select the start and end limits), and covering the full Y-axis range of the chart as it adjusts to fit the data points (typically that full range is bounded by 0-100% but it could dynamically change to show detail if the data fall in a narrower range, say 90-100% or 0-20%).

I set up the RectangularAnnotation with

- AxisX and AxisY tied to the similarly named axes in the associated ChartArea
- ClipToChartArea set to the name of the ChartArea
- IsSizeAlwaysRelative set to FALSE
- X=600, Width=200
- Y=0, Height=100

The problem appears when all of my series point YValues fall below 20%. If I manually set one of the series data points to, say, 80, the RectangularAnnotation displays correctly.

But if I change that last series data point's YValue from 80 to 35, the Chart adjusts and sets the Y axis maximum to 40 properly, but for some reason the BackColored portion of the annotation seems to only extend down from the top of the chart to a Y value of around 6. From there, every time I decrease the Y value of the last series point by 5 or more (e.g., from 35 to 31, the annotation stayed put, but at 30 it moved) the annotation background disappears at a different Y value. By the time I set the final series point Y value less than 20% like the rest of the series, the annotation (or at least the colored rendering of it) disappeared outside the YAxis maximum of 25.

I found the same behavior when creating the annotation and series data programmatically at run time as well.

Much appreciation for any advice.
Thanks, Bob

**edit: modified example for brevity, still shows issue**

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.RectangleAnnotation rectangleAnnotation1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.RectangleAnnotation();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(1D, 30D);
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(2D, 20D);
            System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint dataPoint3 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint(3D, 10D);
            this.chart1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // chart1
            // 
            rectangleAnnotation1.AxisXName = "ChartArea1\\rX";
            rectangleAnnotation1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            rectangleAnnotation1.ClipToChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            rectangleAnnotation1.Height = 100D;
            rectangleAnnotation1.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
            rectangleAnnotation1.Name = "RectangleAnnotation1";
            rectangleAnnotation1.Text = "RectangleAnnotation1";
            rectangleAnnotation1.Width = 1D;
            rectangleAnnotation1.X = 1D;
            rectangleAnnotation1.Y = 0D;
            rectangleAnnotation1.YAxisName = "ChartArea1\\rY";
            this.chart1.Annotations.Add(rectangleAnnotation1);
            chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
            this.chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
            this.chart1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.chart1.Name = "chart1";
            series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
            series1.Name = "Series1";
            series1.Points.Add(dataPoint1);
            series1.Points.Add(dataPoint2);
            series1.Points.Add(dataPoint3);
            this.chart1.Series.Add(series1);
            this.chart1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(776, 426);
            this.chart1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.chart1.Text = "chart1";
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Controls.Add(this.chart1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
```

Comment: Can you possibly provide the related code to show your problem and give me some screen about the RectangularAnnotation  problem?

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I need more reputation points for images.

In InitializeComponent(), these are declared:
rectAnnot1
chartArea1
series1 (line with five DataPoints: [1,30], [2,25], [3, 20], [4,10], [5,60])

For rectAnnot1, these fields are set:
AxisXName = "ChartArea1\\rX"
BackColor =  128,0,128,0
ClipToChartArea = "ChartArea1"
Height = 100
IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false
Width = 1
X = 2
Y = 0
YAxisName = "ChartArea1\\rY"

As is: rectAnnot displays correctly, over the full Y range 0-80
If I change Point 5 to [5,6], it only displays from 12.5-35.

Comment: Please add your code in your question, it will be clear for us to know your code.

Comment: I apologize for trying to paraphrase in the previous response, still learning my way around the site. I tried to make a minimum reproducible example and added the auto-generated designer code to the original post. With the current values in the bar chart the RectangleAnnotation only extends down to Y=17.5 instead of 0.

Comment: based on my test, I didn't reproduce your problem. You can check [this example](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting/RectangleAnnotation/-/php-rectangleannotation-class-examples.html#0x7ea36fda84bd191d80af739c26982efab5a103afac2d50fc7fa0925782ba9c44-33,,48,) to know how to create a RectangleAnnotation successfully.

Comment: Thank you for looking into the problem. I went for Plan B, and figured out how to draw what I need in the Chart.PostPaint event.